# Message: no such window: target window already closed

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

How to switch to the new opened window ?

I tried window name= but I don't know how to get the window name or switch auto to the new opened window cause the previous one closed automatically

```
 try: #after first login, popup disapears
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="chakra-modal--header-1"]/button/svg/path')))
            driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = '//*[@id="chakra-modal--header-1"]/button/svg/path').click() #exit pop-up
        except:
                pass
    
      
    
    #once in page
    
    #HERE I GOT THE ERROR

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[1]/p')))
    elem = driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = '//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[1]/p') #find balance element
```

Comment: Are you sure `driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = '//*[@id="chakra-modal--header-1"]/button/svg/path').click()` worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all opened windows/tabs:

```
all_windows = driver.window_handles
print(all_windows) #to find windows IDs
```

you can number of opened windows/tabs:

```
len(driver.window_handles)
```

To switch:

```
driver.switch_to.window(window_handle ID)
```

Comment: driver.switch_to.window(window_handle ID)
worked so fine thank u

Answer (score 1):

driver.switch_to.window(window_handle ID)
worked just fine thank u